# Facebook like button creating a new page and not displaying correct og:title

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I'm using the facebook like button on my website so that a user can like a predictions for a sports game.

I have the following code for the like button:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<fb:like href="http://www.sportannica.com/games/mlb/1880/predictions/113" show_faces="false" data-send="true" font="verdana" layout="button_count"></fb:like>
```

In the head of the document, I have the following:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Lance Newman's prediction for the Red Sox @ Yankees game on Friday, August 17" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Lance Newman predicted the Yankees to beat the Red Sox (6 to 4) on Friday, August 17 on Sportannica" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.sportannica.com/img/team_icons/New York Yankees/1947.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Sportannica" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789" />
<meta property="og:url" content='http://www.sportannica.com/games/mlb/1880/predictions/113' />
<meta property="og:restrictions:age" content="13+"/>
<meta property="og:determiner"  content="auto" />
```

Someone told me that the reason for the like button triggering the creation of a new page was caused by having an og:type meta tag in the head. I used to have the following in the head of the document as well

```
<meta property="og:type" content="sportannica:victory" />
```

Since I do use this page for a custom action for my application as well. When a user makes a prediction for any game, their prediction is posted on their timeline.

If a user of my site made a prediction for the game found [here](http://www.sportannica.com/games/mlb/1880/predictions/0), then when the form is submitted, the following code would be executed:

```
$queries = array(
            array("method" => "POST", "relative_url" => "/me/sportannica:predict?victory=http://www.sportannica.com/games/".$league."/".$game."/predictions_post/".$_SESSION['id']."")
        );

        try 
        {
            $postResponseA = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
        {
//              echo 'AF error: '.$e.'';
        }
```

Notice how in the above example, instead of the parameter being equal to "predictions", it's "predictions_post".

What's in the open graph tags of the document are contingent upon whether the parameter in the url is set to "predictions_post" or "predictions".

In the head of my document, I have the following php code:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="
<?php
if($tab == "predictions_post")
{
    echo "".$winner_short." victory";    
} elseif($tab == "predictions")
{
    if($gram == 1)
    {
        echo "".$first_name." ".$last_name."'s prediction for the ".$away_team_short." @ ".$home_team_short." game on ".$game_date."";
    } else
    {
        echo "Predictions for ".$away_team_short." @ ".$home_team_short." on ".$game_date."";
    }
}
?>
" />
<meta property="og:description" content="
<?php 
if($tab == "predictions_post")
{
    echo "".$first_name." ".$last_name." predicted the ".$winner_short." to beat the ".$loser_short." (".$win_score." to ".$lose_score.") on ".$game_date." on Sportannica"; 
} elseif($tab == "predictions")
{
    if($gram == 1)
    {
        echo "".$first_name." ".$last_name." predicted the ".$winner_short." to beat the ".$loser_short." (".$win_score." to ".$lose_score.") on ".$game_date." on Sportannica"; 
    } else
    {
        echo "Predictions for ".$away_team_short." @ ".$home_team_short." ".$game_date."";
    }
}
?>
 " />
<?php
if($tab == "predictions_post")
{
?> 
<meta property="og:type" content="sportannica:victory" />
<?php
}
?>
```

But, even when the parameter in the URL is set to "predictions" and the correct open graph tags are display, upon click of the like button, a new page is created and the wrong og:title is displayed.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks,

Lance

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <meta property="og:type" content="sportannica:victory" />
> ```
>
> Are your og:type's with namespace:action approved actions?  As in is
>   victory approved action by facebook?
>
> The type should be either "website"  or if for open graph action posts
>   it should be key:value / namespace:action and the action has to be
>   approved, or it will throw error or be ignored.

---

Try running the buggy URL in the debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: how are you getting the value $tab?